# My img funcition will not render image in shiny

Tags: r, image, user-interface, shiny

I am trying to use an image as the title instead of text, but all I get in the app is the img icon, not the actual image. Here is my code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools) 
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel(img(src = "www/BBBLogo.png",
                   height = 40,
                   width = 60)),
    sidebarLayout(
```

I can't seem to find the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your image is in www subfolder of your app, just do `src = "/BBBLogo.png"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding an image with shinymanager R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64671900/embedding-an-image-with-shinymanager-r)

Comment: That did not work unfortunately

Comment: It works on my setup... double check file name / folder and upgrade shiny

Comment: I tried the link, but that is not exactly what I am trying to do. I think I should just be able to use the img function. I don't think I need a variable though

Comment: Have you tried `src = "BBBLogo.png"` without the `/`?

Comment: Until recently, `img(...)` used to work.  After the update to the browsers, tags$img() will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need `tags$img` and remove `www`.   Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel(tags$img(src = "BBBLogo.png",
                 height = 50,
                 width = 50)),
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between `img()`and `tags$img()`

Comment: As long as the image is in the www folder it should work.  It works for me.  Perhaps you need  `tags$li(a(tags$img(...)))`.

Comment: @HubertL, you are correct in this case.  However, when my company updated browsers recently, my app which was working fine for 10 months stopped working.  After changing img to tags$img, I was able to make it work again.

Comment: Good to know, I thought it was the same function (although why would there be two identical function?)